# Fixed width file String replacement

Tags: unix, sed

I have below file

```
1Thisis  headerinfo   
2this is not my header
2this is a;spjsdlnd   
2dkjcndcn
```

This is a fixed width file.
I am trying the below sed command to replace the "header" string value in the first line with "tricke" value which does not seem to work (I do not have sed -i option, so using below)

```
sed -e '1s/header/tricke/g' TestFile > temptest.txt && temptest.txt TestFile
```

I also need to preserve the fixed width. The replacement for some reason does not seems to work. I am not sure yet what i might be missing. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does `sed -e '1s/header/tricke/g' TestFile` for itself work? It works for me with GNU sed 4.2.2. Is your file called TestFile?

Comment: Yes, its working. Yes, TestFile is my testing file. The display works, but writing the output to same or another file is where i am struck

Comment: So, you are saying that `sed -e '1s/header/tricke/g' TestFile` works and that `sed -e '1s/header/tricke/g' TestFile > temptest.txt` does not work? If so, get a different operating system.

Comment: I am trying different other things and haven't tried the obvious straight forward writing to a file. It works. I am saved from getting a different OS ;). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget the command `mv`:

```
sed -e '1s/header/tricke/g' TestFile > temptest.txt && mv temptest.txt TestFile
```